# Cannot make my array sorting function return correct total

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I cannot figure out my totals are not coming back right.

```
function sortArray(array $input): array {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
        $total = $i * $i;
    }
    return array($total);
}
print_r (sortArray([3,9,5,]));
```

This is what I get back

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting from the function.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Your function named `sortArray`, but it does not sort anything. So what should the function do? Return array of squares of input array?

Comment: @NigelRen Trying to return an array of squared elements

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do this:

```
array_map(function($n){ return $n*$n; }, [3,9,5,]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// first - name your function correctly
// function with name `sortArray` MUST sort array
function getSquares(array $input): array {
    // init `$total` with empty array
    $total = [];
    // forget about `for` loop
    // `foreach` will do ALL the job
    foreach ($input as $element) {
        // append each element to `$total`
        $total[] = $element * $element;
    }

    // `$total` is already an array, no need to use `array()`
    return $total;
}
print_r (getSquares([3,9,5,]));
```

Another answer shows you `array_map` function, as you can see in that case it takes less code. And since **php7.4** can be reduced to:

```
print_r(
    array_map(fn($n) => $n*$n, [3,9,5,])
);
```

Comment: Ah, I had considered a foreach loop, but didn't try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you're not sorting the array, you're mapping it, so you may want to change the function name.

```
function sortArray(array $input): array {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
        $total[] = $input[$i] * $input[$i];
    }
    return $total;
}
print_r (sortArray([3,9,5,]));

Result: Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 81 [2] => 25 )
```